# I installed ubuntu using 4gb usb stick, i overwrote windows and when i restart i get the message no bootable device

Tags: boot

I have an 8 year old acer aspire es14. I have tried reinstalling ubuntu but still receive the same message

Comment: Boot the install-media in "try-mode", start a Terminal (Shell) and type `sudo fdisk -l`. Hopefully you may also log in here and copy (mark text with left mouse button, right click on the text) & paste what you see into the text above (click edit). Append the output of `sudo efibootmgr -v` after it.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS system? Have you updated UEFI from Acer? If UEFI, generally you have to set "trust" to enable boot of "unknown" which is the ubuntu entry. Once you set trust then it works. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to reinstall Windows (or Ubuntu).
Your data won't be lost (unless you wiped your disk during the installation)

To reinstall Windows, create the installation media from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10).

Then, just follow the steps on the installation media.

Next, reinstall Ubuntu and make sure Secure Boot is disabled and check your USB to make sure it's not corrupted. You can also make changes as needed with [EasyUEFI](https://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html).

If you'd like a complete guide on dualbooting Windows and Ubuntu, click [here](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-dual-boot-mode-windows/).

Edit: I just noticed your USB stick was 4GB. In that case, you'll need a larger USB for Windows (8GB minimum, 16GB recommended)